# Reading .xlsx file From android app Using POI 3.17

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

Hi I have code which is used for reading .xlsx file.

I read .xls file but when we execute .xlsx file we can't run.

```
File fileFolder = null;
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    //MilkCollection.xls
String csvFile = "newRateChartDB.xlsx";
    Workbook workbook = null;
    Sheet sheet;
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator;
    fileFolder = new File(sd.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Test");
    File inputWorkbook = new File(fileFolder + File.separator + csvFile);
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    try {
        String excelFilePath = "newRateChartDB.xlsx";
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputWorkbook);
        if (csvFile.endsWith(".xls")) {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        } else if (csvFile.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
            try {

              //  workbook =    WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileFolder + File.separator + csvFile));
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                }
                System.out.print(" - ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        workbook.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I got exception when executeL:

> 01-16 14:12:14.452 9767-9767/com.mind.Test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                    Process: com.mind.Test, PID: 9767
>                                                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory;
>                                                                        at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.(PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:41)
>                                                                        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:161)
>                                                                        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.(OPCPackage.java:141)
>                                                                        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:97)
>                                                                        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:324)
>                                                                        at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
>                                                                        at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:295)
>                                                                        at
>   com.mind.Test.setting.RateAmountSettingsActivity.ReadExceklData(RateAmountSettingsActivity.java:386)
>                                                                        at
>   com.mind.Test.setting.RateAmountSettingsActivity.access$000(RateAmountSettingsActivity.java:50)
>                                                                        at
>   com.mind.Test.setting.RateAmountSettingsActivity$2.onClick(RateAmountSettingsActivity.java:129)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
>                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mind.Test-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mind.Test-2/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.mind.Test-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                                                                        at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                        at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.(PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:41) 
>                                                                        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:161) 
>                                                                        at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.(OPCPackage.java:141) 
>                                                                        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:97) 
>                                                                        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:324) 
>                                                                        at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37) 
>                                                                        at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:295) 
>                                                                        at
>   com.mind.Test.setting.RateAmountSettingsActivity.ReadExceklData(RateAmountSettingsActivity.java:386) 
>                                                                        at
>   com.mind.Test.setting.RateAmountSettingsActivity.access$000(RateAmountSettingsActivity.java:50) 
>                                                                        at
>   com.mind.Test.setting.RateAmountSettingsActivity$2.onClick(RateAmountSettingsActivity.java:129) 
>                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
>                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
>                                                                     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory
>                                                                        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                             ... 20 more
>                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack trace available

While I have attached this third library in gradle also.

```
    implementation files('libs/poi-3.17.jar')
    implementation files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar')
    implementation files('libs/poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar')
```